# Изменить ширину столбца selectOneListbox (JSF, Primefaces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Не могу найти, как изменить ширину столбца в элементе selectOneListbox, желательно чтобы ширина автоматически подгонялась под самую длинную строку.

Код JFS

```
<p:panel id="puserList" header="Список пользователей" style="margin:10px; text-align: center; width:20%;">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">              
               <p:selectOneListbox id="userL" value="#{adminS.user}" var="t" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{adminS.userList}" var="user" itemLabel="#{user.fullName}" itemValue="#{user}" />
                    <p:column style="width:300px">
                        <h:outputText value="#{t.fullName}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:selectOneListbox>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

style надо применять не на столбец, а на сам элемент ))